# Как настроить Visual Studio чтобы автоматически ставился обратный слеш в string

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Как настроить Visual Studio чтобы автоматически ставился обратный слеш в string
Как например Eclipse.

Comment: Яп какой? Если C#, то `@` перед строкой. А вообще `\` - почти во всех яп универсальный экранный символ

Comment: @Александр Ну нет, вот смотри  такой код конечно выдаст ошибку
`string a = "<a href=""></a>";`

Я хочу чтоб какую нибудь кнопку автоматически делал так
' string a = "<a href=\"\"></a>"; '

Comment: язык какой? C# или C++?

Comment: @Александр C#, .............